# Multiple occurrences of text in a string

Tags: c#, string, loops, for-loop, find

How could I use a for loop to go through each iteration of a given phrase in a string? For instance, say I had the following string:

Hey, this is an example string. A string is a collection of characters.

And every time there was an "is", I wanted to assign the three characters after it to a new string. I understand how to do that ONCE, but I'm trying to figure out how a for loop could be used to go through multiple instances of the same word.

Comment: do you want something like: string st = "Hey, this is an example string. A string is a collection of characters.";    st=st.replace("is","is+3char");   var arrayOfSplittedSts = st.Split(new[]{"is+3char"}, System.StringSplitOptions.None); ?

Answer (score 2):

If you *must* use a for-loop for whatever reason, you can replace the relevant part of the [code provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711984/947484) by ja72 with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (text[i] == 'i' && text[i+1] == 's')
        sb.Append(text.Substring(i + 2, 3));
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment here, hence posting it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text=@"Hey, this is an example string. A string is a collection of characters.";

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        int i=-1;
        while ((i=text.IndexOf("is", i+1))>=0)
        {
            sb.Append(text.Substring(i+2, 3));
        }
        string result=sb.ToString();
    }


//result " is an a "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
  Regex re = new Regex("(?:is)(.{3})");
```

This regex looks for is `(?:is)`, and takes the next three characters `(.{3})`

Then you use the regex to find all matches: [Regex.Matches()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx). This will return a match for each `is` found in the string, followed by 3 characters. Each match has two groups:

- Group 0: that includes is and the next three characters
- Group 1: which includes the next thress characters

  Matches matches = re.Matches("Hey, this is an example string. A string is a collection of characters.");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Match m in matches)
    {
        sb.Append(m.Groups[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx).Value);
    }

Using Regex is much faster than looping through the characters of the string. Even more if you use [RegexOptions.Compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) in your regex constructor: [Regex Constructor (String, RegexOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5845fdz.aspx)